# Appium unable to start App on iPhone simulator

Tags: ios, cordova, appium, hybrid-mobile-app, webdriver-io

My goal is to run some end 2 end smoke tests against an hybrid App built with Cordova.

I am using [Appium](https://www.npmjs.com/package/appium) (driven by [WebDriver.IO](http://webdriver.io/)) and I can successfully spin up in an emulator the Android App and run the tests against it.

I can't though even start the iOS App on the iPhone simulator.

WebDriver.IO spits out this error:

> "ERROR: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: "Command 'Scripts/bootstrap.sh -d' exited with code 1"."

And checking the logs of the iPhone simulator I see:

> "Program specified by service does not contain any valid architectures for this system."

More details:

- The app gets installed and starts but it crashes right away. I get the same with another demo app for iOS.
- The app correctly starts when launched from XCode

---

What am I doing wrong?

- Is it a **certificate issue**? (the App is signed with an Apple Developer Account and works when installed on real devices) -- **PS.** No
- Do I need a **driver for iOS**? (I had to download a specific version of ChromeDriver for the Android app but I did not find further instructions regarding a driver for iOS) -- **PS.** No, it was already installed together with Appium: `/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent`

---

**UPDATE - partial success:**

I managed to manually install and run the App on the device:
I zipped the *.app* file found in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{app name}/Build/` (that is correctly built for x86_64 systems - thanks @SushiHangover) and started it on the simulator.

Pointing `wdio.conf.js` to the new *.app.zip* file now it gets correctly installed by Appium before each test run. 
(I can verify that the App gets correctly installed because I can tap on it and start it afterwards).

**I still get the 1st error though before each test run!**

vvv

LOGS with the error:

```
[debug] [XCUITest] The app has been installed successfully.
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'appInstalled' logged at 1545635044697 (02:04:04 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time))
[XCUITest] Using WDA path: '/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Documents/CODE/ACTIVE/APPIUM/asialgearoid/mine2/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent'
[XCUITest] Using WDA agent: '/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Documents/CODE/ACTIVE/APPIUM/asialgearoid/mine2/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj'
[debug] [XCUITest] No obsolete cached processes from previous WDA sessions listening on port 8100 have been found
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[JSONWP Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"errno":"ECONNREFUSED","code":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":8100}
[debug] [XCUITest] WDA is not listening at 'http://localhost:8100/'
[debug] [XCUITest] WDA is currently not running. There is nothing to cache
[debug] [XCUITest] Trying to start WebDriverAgent 2 times with 10000ms interval
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'wdaStartAttempted' logged at 1545635044905 (02:04:04 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time))
[XCUITest] Launching WebDriverAgent on the device
[debug] [XCUITest] Carthage found: '/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Documents/CODE/ACTIVE/APPIUM/asialgearoid/mine2/node_modules/.bin/carthage'
[debug] [XCUITest] Running WebDriverAgent bootstrap script to install dependencies
[XCUITest] [1mFetching dependencies
[XCUITest] Error: Command "bootstrap" does not exist.
...
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'wdaStartFailed' logged at 1545635057640 (02:04:17 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time))
[debug] [XCUITest] Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: "Command 'Scripts/bootstrap.sh -d' exited with code 1".
```

---

---

After further digging I found out how to reproduce the error:

```
$ cd /myTestingProject/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent
$ ./Scripts/bootstrap.sh
```

Output:

> Fetching dependencies
>   Error: Command "bootstrap" does not exist.

Still unsolved.

Comment: Need to build your iOS app for `x86_64` to run on the simulator (instead of ARM which is for physical devices)

Comment: PS. I solved in this way: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/9344#issuecomment-449702706